# TabPageIndicator has totally lost its style.. why?

Tags: android, android-tabs, viewpagerindicator

I have created a dialog with a TabPageIndicator inside it. The problem is that the menus looks like TextViews (not clickable static white text) instead of tabs like expected.

In the image attached you can see the result:

[image: Image describing the tabs]

What am I doing wrong? I have no idea of what it can be, so I attach the code that might be useful to understand the problem (I have tried also to totally disable my custom style with any success, so I won't post that for this reason).

Main class:

```
public class NotificationsFragment extends DialogFragment {
    private final RpcHandler rpcHandler;

    public NotificationsFragment(){
        rpcHandler = RpcHandler.getInstance();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_notifications, null, false);

        TabPageIndicator titles = (TabPageIndicator) root.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) root.findViewById(R.id.pager);

        final String[] titleNames = new String[]{"All", "Exception", "Warnings", "BadRPC"};

        FragmentStatePagerAdapter adapter = new FragmentStatePagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()) {
            @Override
            public String getPageTitle(int position) {
                return titleNames[position];
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return titleNames.length;
            }

            @Override
            public Fragment getItem(final int position) {
                return new Fragment(){
                    public ArrayList<NotificationsHandler.NotificationEvent> notifications;

                    @Override
                    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater _layoutInflater, ViewGroup container,
                            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                        [...] // useless for this problem

                        return convertView;
                    }
                };
            }
        };
        pager.setAdapter(adapter);
        titles.setViewPager(pager);

        Rect displayRectangle = new Rect();
        Window window = getActivity().getWindow();
        window.getDecorView().getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(displayRectangle);

        root.setMinimumWidth((int) (displayRectangle.width() * 0.7));
        root.setMinimumHeight((int) (displayRectangle.height() * 0.7));
        return root;
    }
}
```

While this is the related XML:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <com.viewpagerindicator.TabPageIndicator
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        />
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Any idea? :) thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem adding these lines to my style:

```
<item name="vpiIconPageIndicatorStyle">@style/Widget.IconPageIndicator</item>
<item name="vpiTabPageIndicatorStyle">@style/Widget.TabPageIndicator</item>
```